# Changing Outlook event via importing CSV file

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, csv, calendar

I add events to an Outlook calendar by importing a CSV file that is created from an Excel spreadsheet. If I change info in the spreadsheet, and re-import the CSV, how can I ensure the original entry is changed, as opposed to a new event being created? Is there any way to remove events from calendar via opening and importing a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you can first archive calendar items which you want to change. This will move calendar items from your calendar folder to local arhcive.pst file. Then you import the CSV to your calendar folder. New items will be added.

Comment: Ah, I never used the archive feature before! Thanks, this'll do! Now to wrangle up some VBA to archive the calendar with the a single click...